# Marquee in HTML

Tags: html, marquee

how would I go about making a marquee in html?
could I define everything i.e. speed, looping, text color, background color, direction, etc.  With just html or should I need to know another language to define those aspects?
Also could I implement an image in the marquee?

Comment: I'm tempted to vote this offensive.

Comment: >.>  That's why I said "or should I need to know another language to define those aspects"  I.e. Javascript.  I know most of html is obsolete.

Comment: Why, why would you want to make a marquee in html? What have your users done to offend you?

Comment: There are a lot of uppity web devs against using it in favor of CSS and JS solutions. The tradeoff you have to ask yourself is which is the more evil of two hacks. The kind that isn't standard (but works in most browsers) that only takes one line of code, or the one that that takes 20 or more lines of code, might not work in as many browsers and requires it to be an extra .js file that is src'd.

Answer (score 7):

[You don't want to use that tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_tag). Really. [It is evil](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-tag-reference/html-marquee-tag.php).

For alternatives, check out:

- [The Silky Smooth Marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)
- [jScroller2](http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/)
- [Cross Browser Marquee](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltick2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

@Paolo is correct, you also might wanna look into tools to do similar things but have much more functionality. [jScroller](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do images in the marquee tag:

http://jdstiles.com/java/scrollers/scrollingimage.html

But it's not a good tag to use.  Go for one of the many javascript libraries that do this, such as this [Cross Browser Marquee](http://nuclearscripts.com/javascript/scripts-and-programs/text-effects/cross-browser-marquee.html) that allows you to set all the parameters you like.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<MARQUEE id=Marquee2 title="" 
style="BORDER-RIGHT: 1px; BORDER-TOP: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; Z-INDEX: 2; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-LEFT: 1px; WIDTH: 5.197in; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px; HEIGHT: 0.156in" 
trueSpeed scrollDelay=150 MsoTextAlign="General">My Text Goes Here</MARQUEE>
```

Comment: 1997 called. They want their Angelfire pages back.

Comment: I want to give you +1 simply because I think you went to so much effort to get so much badness into your answer and you should be rewarded :) Still, I just know that someone will see my +1 and take your answer seriously, so I'm sorry, I just can't do it.

Comment: This is a black hole answer, bad advice cannot escape it's gravity

Comment: I thought it was geocities or tripod :D

Answer (score 0):

You can change the speed, direction and looping in the html but to edit background color you will need to use CSS. To style the text color, you do not need to style the <marquee> but you need to style the elements INSIDE the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a marquee in HTML using Cycle 2 Jquery plugin :
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"  data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-speed="9000" data-cycle-timeout="1"  data-cycle-easing="linear" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-slides="> div" >
  <div>  Text 1  </div>
  <div>  Text 2  </div>
</div>
```