# An alternative to the ancient "marquee" tag?

Tags: html, asp.net, standards, marquee

What is the standard equivalent of the "marquee" tag?

I'm looking for a solution in HTML, C#, asp.NET or ASPX, jquery, java script

Comment: Is a solution in JavaScript out of question?

Comment: no it not out of question please provide

Comment: @Matti I guess he's after a JavaScript solution wrapped into a ASP.NET component or whatever.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687523/marquee-in-html

Comment: @user287745 - Have you ever considered using a "real" handle/name?

Comment: @Matti @Trinidad not that those are out of the question. See Matt Berseth's article here: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/cnn_style_scrolling_ticker_wit.html for instance.

Comment: @drachenstern: I have no idea who "Matt Berseth" is and it would probably take me less time to whip up a three-liner in jQuery than to figure out how to use some control.

Comment: WHAT ARE YOU PEOPLE DOING????  *Do you realize what he's going to do with this information???*

Comment: @Matti then perhaps it's a good thing I linked you to his site. Also, he obviously would like an easy to use asp.net control, and I linked him a control.

Comment: @Will I don't. Perhaps an explanation of what you're driving at would be more useful than a very vehement-sounding but cryptic comment implying that there's some major unidentified problem with either the poster's intentions or the way people are responding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "marquee" tag was not included in the standard because it's a "visual" tag, not a "semantic" tag. As such, none of the languages that you want have an exact equivalent.

I suggest using Javascript to do animations on your webpage. (I hear that [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is a great framework to get started with.)

**Note:**

As [someone pointed out in MSO chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/484548#484548), there is actually a jQuery plugin already written to do what you want. See then [jQuery marquee plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/marquee). Also, there is this [demo from Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html).

Comment: +1 for "visual not semantic" ... that's a good point that a lot of people forget. HTML is for markup, not styling (despite the strong history to the contrary)

Comment: While the marquee tag is deprecated as a "don't do that," the marquee tag was never part of the spec at all. It was a proprietary IE tag.

Answer (score 2):

*Technically*, the standards equivalent is the [CSS3 marquee module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/). (Technically because good luck finding a browser vendor that will ever actually implement it.)