# asp.net c# marquee with sql ,innertext not use new line

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql-server-2008, marquee

I'm new in programming field ......so please give proper answer for that que.

I'm using dynamic marquee with sql database for "company news", there code run properly but marquee not create new line for new point.

html code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="style42" Width="762px" 
    BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" BackColor="#78BBE6" 
    Height="267px">
    <div style="width: 762px; " class="style41">
       <marquee id="mar1" runat="server" direction="up" onmouseover="this.stop()" 
                onmouseout="this.start()" scrollamount="2" scrolldelay="1" 
                class="style43" >
            <strong>
            </strong>
       </marquee>   
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

c# code:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection obj = new SqlConnection("data source=DHAVAL-PC;"+
                       "initial catalog=user_master;"+
                       "integrated security=true;user id=sa;password=1234");
    string login1 = "select * from admin_data";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(login1,obj);
    obj.Open();
    SqlDataReader user = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    if (user.HasRows)
    {
        user.Read();
        SqlDataReader t1;
        user.Close();
        t1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        t1.Read();               
        this.mar1.InnerHtml= t1[6].ToString();  
           //what to do for newpoint in newline                             
        obj.Close();
     }
 }
```

there in my database only one field for entering news containts...
when use textbox for display news it work good..it show new point in new line..but marquee not display like textbox.

please give me proper suggestion .....

Comment: do you want your next news to come under first news?

Comment: I would strongly suggest avoiding use of the `<marquee>` tag - it's not really supported consistently. Take a look at this question and its accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854008/an-alternative-to-the-ancient-marquee-tag?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Entering a newline in a textbox produces a newline character (`\n`) in C#. HTML ignores newline characters, to force a newline in HTML you have to use the `<br />`tag:

```
this.mar1.InnerHtml= t1[6].ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
 this.mar1.InnerHtml= t1[6].ToString();  
       //what to do for newpoint in newline
```

to

```
 this.mar1.InnerHtml+= t1[6].ToString()+"<br/>";  
       //what to do for newpoint in newline
```

or you have new line character in your single record then you should do like this

```
this.mar1.InnerHtml+= t1[6].ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");
```